# Get general data only once after login?

Tags: angularjs

A timesheet object has a task_link which links to a project.  I want to display the project on a timesheet detail screen.  Ideally I want to load all the task_links and projects one time (when the user logs in), and reload them if necessary.  How can I do this?

Now I have this in my TimesheetDetailCtrl, but it looks terrible:

```
.controller('TimesheetDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $filter, TaskLinks, Projects, Tasks, Timesheets) {
    Timesheets.query({q: {id_eq: $stateParams.timesheetId }}).$promise.then(function(data, status) {
      $scope.timesheet = data[0];
        TaskLinks.query().$promise.then(function(data, status){
            $scope.project_id = $filter('filter')(data, {id: $scope.timesheet.task_link_id})[0].project_id;
            Projects.query().$promise.then(function(data, status){
              $scope.project = $filter('filter')(data, {id: $scope.project_id})[0];
            });
        });
      })
})
```

The service looks like this at the moment:

```
.factory('Projects', function($resource) {
  return $resource('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/projects');
})

.factory('TaskLinks', function($resource) {
  var task_links = $resource('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/task_links', {},
    {query:
      {
        cache: true,
        method: 'GET',
        isArray: true
      }}
  );
  return task_links;
})
```

What can I change in order to just have something I can call after the user is logged in, without always need to work around the promises?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you can use `$emit` to trigger the event from the controller and use $on on to catch the login event

**Controller1**

```
scope.$emit("UserLoggedIn", value);
```

In the **Controller2** the event that will be captured using `$on` like:

```
$scope.$on("UserLoggedIn", function(event, ars){
   ... //your event has been triggered.    
});
```